# What media formats supported by LR for embedding metadata?

Tags: lightroom, metadata, xmp

I am writing an article about migrating Lightroom catalogs to Daminion via XMP metadata.

Does anybody know what media formats supported by LR for embedding metadata. Except JPEG and TIFF formats.

Answer (score 2):

Lightroom stores metadata in the XMP format and supports EXIF, IPTC (IIM), and TIFF metadata definitions (it converts and stores those as XMP as well). Where the information is stored depends on the format of the image the metadata describes. If the the original format supports XMP, it is embedded in the file. If not (proprietary RAW formats are an example), you will see a "sidecar" file generated with the .xmp extension.

Answer (score 1):

Lightroom can embed develop settings into the metadata of JPEG, TIFF or PSD files.

Here's a screenshot from the Metadata tab of the Catalog Settings dialog..

[image]